# What's the difference between Innate and At-will spell casting in D&D 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

The Monster Manual references both these ideas but it's not clear to me whether these are interchangeable terms or if there's some difference between them.

In FoundryVTT both options are provided but again the difference is not clear.

Answer (score 12):

#### Innate spellcasting

[Innate Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#InnateSpellcasting) is a special trait used in monster stat blocks to designate that a creature has some spellcasting abilities "innately", literally meaning it was born that way. It is defined in the introduction to the Monster Manual.

Innate spellcasting has several restrictions, unless otherwise noted, for instance:

- a spell is always cast at its lowest level
- some innate spells have special rules or restrictions
- innate spells can't be swapped out

Here is the full description:

> **Innate Spellcasting**
> A monster with the innate ability to cast spells has the Innate Spellcasting special trait. Unless noted otherwise, an innate spell of 1st level or higher is always cast at its lowest possible level and can’t be cast at a higher level. If a monster has a cantrip where its level matters and no level is given, use the monster’s challenge rating.
>
> An innate spell can have special rules or restrictions. For example, a drow mage can innately cast the levitate spell, but the spell has a “self only” restriction, which means that the spell affects only the drow mage.
>
> A monster’s innate spells can’t be swapped out with other spells. If a monster’s innate spells don’t require attack rolls, no attack bonus is given for them.

#### At Will

At will simply means an unlimited number of times per day. An example from the Monster Manual, the [Oni](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16971-oni) can cast invisibility and darkness at will, meaning it can cast those spells an unlimited number of times a day.

At will spellcasting is not limited to just innate spellcasters. Cantrips are at will:

> **[Cantrips](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Cantrips)**
> A cantrip is a spell that can be cast at will, without using a spell slot and without being prepared in advance. Repeated practice has fixed the spell in the caster's mind and infused the caster with the magic needed to produce the effect over and over. A cantrip's spell level is 0.

The term at will is also used elsewhere to mean a spell can be cast an unlimited number of times a day. For example, the warlock's [Armor of Shadows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#ArmorofShadows) feature allows the warlock to cast *mage armor* at will. Another example, the wizard's 18th level class feature [Spell Mastery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#SpellMastery) allows the wizard to cast some spells at will.

Comment: Might be useful to add that there can be spells that are both innate and at will, for example, the Oni that you cite has innate at will spellcasting for darkness and invisibility, while it has innate 1/day casting for charm person, cone of cold, gaseous form and sleep

Comment: Does the magic that some races have also count as "innate spellcasting", for instance Firbolg Magic? Or just monsters.

Comment: @Senmurv - Comments aren't for questions. That is a rather excellent question you can ask, and one I vaguely recall answering (or something along these lines) in the past. I would like to recommend you post your comment as it's own question, it's a rather good one to pose.